# Photo gallery lagging in OS X Safari

Tags: javascript, html, safari

I wrote this photo gallery to show some photos with autoplay. (The autoplay stops when the user selects a photo manually)
I'm experiencing some lag in OS X Safari (scrolling isn't smooth anymore). OS X Firefox and iOS Safari are fine. Does anyone know why this is lagging and how to fix it?

```
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="preview">
        <img name="preview" src="content/pictures/praxis/raeumlichkeiten/1.jpg" alt="Räumlichkeiten">
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnails">
        <?php 
            for($j = 1; $j <= 11; $j++){
                ?><img onclick="preview.src=thumbnail<?php echo($j);?>.src;auto=false;" name="thumbnail<?php echo($j);?>" src="content/pictures/praxis/raeumlichkeiten/<?php echo($j);?>.jpg" alt="Thumbnail<?php echo($j);?>">
            <?php }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var k = 1;
    var auto = true;
    function changeGalleryPicture() {
            if(auto==true){
                preview.src="content/pictures/praxis/raeumlichkeiten/"+k+".jpg";
                if(k==11){
                    k = 0;
                }
                k++;
            }
        }
    setInterval(changeGalleryPicture, 5000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the sizes of the images is to big. Try to scale down the preview image to a lower quality or size :)